# qt5 windows 10 mobile keyboard

Tags: keyboard, uwp, qt5, windows-10-mobile

On windows 10 mobile (UWP), the (windows built in)virtual keyboard, which pops up as soon as you focus a textinput element, does not change the screensize, and therefor overlap my input element.

Is there a possibilty, to
 1. connect to an event like keyboard open/close
 2. get the height of the virtual keyboard

Or any other workaround?

Comment: You are looking for the [InputPane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane) class.

Comment: thanks, that looks pretty good, it will try it soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using getting the inputmethod Object with QGuiApplication::inputMethod(); , connect its to visibleChanged() signal
and then request the Rectangle with keyboardRectangle();